# PYTHON - extract list element using keyword

Tags: python, list, pdfplumber

My goal is to extract an element from many list that similar like this. Taking elements that is food.

```
test_list =
['Tools: Pen',
'Food: Sandwich',
'Fruit: Apple'
]
```

I the final result would be **"Sandwich"** by look list element with the word "Food:" and split from there.

My usual method is lookup by index

```
test_list[1].split(': ')[1]
```

However, I go through many lists that number of elements is varied, and I want to look up the food item in the "food:" section. I don't know if there is a function that would help me choose element from a list using "keyword search"

Another example,

```
test_list_2 =
['Tools: Pen',
'Tree: Willow'
'Food: Drumstick',
'Fruit: Apple'
]
```

With the same lines of code, test_list_2 result would be **"Drumstick"**

Please kindly help my find a way to do that in Python. Thank you

Comment: *keyword* concept is generally referring in *dictionary* context. So the answer is obvious...

Answer (score 2):

I would consider using a dictionary for this application.

to translate a list of the form you gave into a dictionary:

```
test_dict = {i.split(": ")[0]: i.split(": ")[1] for i in test_list}
```

And then you can access elements by key

```
test_dict['Food']
```

Comment: Hi, what if this list is parsed from a pdf. I can't change it or make a dictionary. Is there any way to lookup an element without using dictionary?

Comment: You can view the answer from @Daniel Hao in this case. May I ask how you are parsing the pdf?

Comment: @HayTeam - one way is to loop as I've suggested in the post.

Comment: You can also use list comprehension to translate a list to a dictionary. I will update my answer with this solution.

Comment: I use pdfplumber and use .split(\n) on the pdf. and I only parse the info in each list element. Idk if that make sense or the most effective way to parse pdf. I parse multiple pdf using a loop as well. most pdf has same format, but some has extra space/notes. and it messed up the code if i use index to find a specific info

Comment: @HayTeam can you give an example of when the indexing doesn't work?

Comment: compare between test_list vs test_list_2, Food is index as [1] in test_list and as [2] in test_list_2. so if i apply LIST[1].split(': ')[1] it would not work for all the list.

Comment: @IddoSadeh i looked up list comprehension and it work perfect for my application. thank you

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a [dictionary](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp).

```
test_list_2 =
{'Tools': 'Pen',
'Tree': 'Willow',
'Food': 'Drumstick',
'Fruit': 'Apple'
}

print(test_list_2["Tools"])
```

Comment: Hi, what if this list is parsed from a pdf. I can't change it or make a dictionary. Is there any way to lookup an element without using dictionary?

Comment: "I can't change it or make it a dictionary" -- Yes you can, just split it using commas as you were doing before and do `test_list_2[key_from_list] = value_from_list`

Comment: @HayTeam you can definitely make it a dictionary.